# How to config Apache via command line?

Tags: node.js, apache, command-line, server, virtualhost

I'd like to manage servers/virtual-hosts through an interface programmed in **node.js**. However, I'm struggling to get/set configurations on **Apache**.

Executing `apachectl -S` is the only way I've found to do that, but its response is not friendly to use. 
Is there any easier way? Something I do that returns a *JSON* or *Array* with the configuration?